# Which polynomial functions can satisfy $f(x)\cdot f({1\over x}) = f(x) + f({1\over x})$?

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

I read in my class notes that there are only two polynomials functions which can satisfy the relation
$$
 f(x) \cdot f(\frac{1}{x}) =  f(x) + f(\frac{1}{x})
$$
 , which are 
$1 \pm x^n$ . I am not able to understand why only these 2 polynomial functions are able to satisfy the given relation , can't there be any other polynomial function which will satisfy the given relation ? Please help me to solve this query .

Comment: The $0$ polynomial function and the constant $2$ polynomial function satisfy it as well.

Comment: @JVHD2334 These correspond to the quoted solution with $n=0$.

Comment: Of course, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The relation is equivalent to
$$\Big(f(x)-1\Big)\Big(f(\tfrac1x)-1\Big)=1.$$

---

**Details:**

> Let $d=\deg f$ so that $g(x)=x^df(\tfrac1x)$ is a polynomial. Then the  above shows that  $$x^d=\Big(f(x)-1\Big)\Big(g(x)-x^d\Big).$$ It follows that $f(x)-1=\pm x^n$ for some integer $n$ with $0\leq n\leq d$, and so $f(x)=1\pm x^n$. Conversely it is easily verified that for every integer $n\geq0$ you have $$(1\pm x^n)(1\pm x^{-n})=(1\pm x^n)+(1\pm x^{-n}),$$ when all the signs agree.